# Exception in Webjob trigger is logged multiple times

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs

I have set up a sample WebJob that logs to Application Insights. However, all my exceptions get logged multiple times - two times if I use a timer trigger, three times if I use ServiceBus triggers.

Full code is available [here](https://github.com/LXBdev/WebJob-netcore-sample).

My logging configuration:

```json
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    }
  },
```

My code:

```cs
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
// ...
builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    // ...
});

// ...

    public async Task MyTimerTriggerOperation([TimerTrigger("0/15 * * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Do some work...
        await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);

        throw new Exception("test");
    }
```

The exceptions are logged multiple times, both to the console and to Application Insights.
The categories are `Host.Results`, `Host.Executor` (if using ServiceBus) and the name of my function (`Function.MyTimerTriggerOperation`).

I don't want to disable all logs for `Host.Results` and `Host.Executor`. Do I have other options to limit the number of exceptions in my logs?

Comment: To resolve that, you could renew message lock just before it's about to expire using BrokeredMessage.RenewLockAsync().
Please refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38768481/16630207).

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT What lock is expiring if I throw an exception in a timer trigger?